# WooCommerce GraphQL API Returns Incomplete List of Product Variations

Tags: wordpress, next.js, woocommerce, graphql

I'm working with WooCommerce on WordPress and using GraphQL to fetch product variations. I've encountered an issue where the GraphQL API only returns 10 variations for a product that has 12. This behavior is causing problems on the front-end of my Next.js application where I need to display all variations.

Here's the GraphQL query I'm using:

```
query GetProduct($id: ID!) {
  product(id: $id) {
    ... on VariableProduct {
      variations {
        nodes {
          id
          price
          attributes {
            nodes {
              name
              value
            }
          }
          image {
            sourceUrl
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Expected behavior: The query should return all variations of the product.

Actual behavior: Only 10 variations are returned.

I suspect it might be related to a default pagination limit in the GraphQL or WooCommerce settings, but I haven't found where this could be adjusted.

Has anyone faced a similar issue, or can anyone spot what I might be doing wrong here? Any guidance on how to ensure all product variations are returned in the response would be greatly appreciated.

Some image

```
https://i.stack.imgur.com/APre8.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/BvSkY.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/vkmbd.png
```

Answer (score 0):

variations(first: 200)

Found the solution. attr first will force return number of nodes.